# Make User Input Match Specific Criteria (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently working on a text based game for a school project. My only issue is that I cannot get my program to print 'Invalid input' when the user input does not include 'Take' and [item name]. So the item is added to inventory as long as the user input is 'Take'.

`

```
import sys

def start_menu():
    # Print start menu and commands
    print('<>' * 50) # Print lines to separate text
    title = (r"""  
            ╔═╗┬─┐┌─┐┌─┐┌┬┐  ╔═╗┬ ┬┬─┐┌─┐┌┬┐┬┌┬┐  ┌─┐┌─┐  ╔╦╗┌─┐┌─┐┬─┐┌─┐┌─┐┌┐┌
            ║ ╦├┬┘├┤ ├─┤ │   ╠═╝└┬┘├┬┘├─┤││││ ││  │ │├┤   ║║║├┤ ├┤ ├┬┘├┤ ├┤ │││
            ╚═╝┴└─└─┘┴ ┴ ┴   ╩   ┴ ┴└─┴ ┴┴ ┴┴─┴┘  └─┘└    ╩ ╩└─┘└─┘┴└─└─┘└─┘┘└┘
                """)
    print(title)
    print('<>' * 50 )  # Print lines to separate text
    print('You are a Spy visiting the Great Pyramid of Meereen. You must make your way from the top of the\n'
          'Pyramid to the Dragon Pit. Collect all of the items along the way to help defeat the two Dragons.\n'
          'If you are successful you will put an end to Queen Daenerys reign and save the Seven Kingdoms.\n'
          '\nHappy Adventuring!')
    print('<>' * 50)
    print('Input move: North, South, East or West')
    print('Input "Take [item name]" to add item to inventory')
    print('Input "Exit" to quit game')
    print('<>' * 50)
start_menu()

# Dictionary of rooms and items
rooms = {
        'Terrace': {'East': 'Daenerys Chambers'},
        'Daenerys Chambers': {'West': 'Terrace', 'East': 'Barristan\'s Chambers', 'South': 'Royal Chambers',
                              'item': 'Dragon Necklace'},
        'Barristan\'s Chambers': {'West': 'Daenerys Chambers', 'item': 'Barristan\'s Sword'},
        'Royal Chambers': {'North': 'Daenerys Chambers', 'South': 'Torture Cells',
                           'West': 'Audience Chamber', 'East': 'Stables', 'item': 'Milk of the Poppy'},
        'Audience Chamber': {'East': 'Royal Chambers', 'item': 'Torch'},
        'Stables': {'West': 'Royal Chambers', 'item': 'Health Potion'},
        'Torture Cells': {'North': 'Royal Chambers', 'East': 'Dragon Pit', 'item': 'Magic Potion'},
        'Dragon Pit': {'West': 'Torture Cells', 'Item': 'Dragons'}
    }

def gameplay_loop():
    move_direction = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
    inventory = []
    current_room = 'Terrace'

    # Gameplay loop
    while True:
        # Display Inventory
        print('Inventory', inventory, '\n')

        # Shows current location and item
        if current_room == 'Terrace':
            print('You are on the {}.\n'.format(current_room))
        if current_room == 'Daenerys Chambers' or current_room == 'Barristan\'s Chambers':
            print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room))
            if item not in inventory:
                print('Item:', item, '\n')
            else:
                print('You have collected all of the items in this room.\n')
        elif current_room != 'Terrace':
            print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))
            if current_room == 'Torture Cells':
                print('A sign reads: "Beware of Dragon Pit: East"')
            if item not in inventory:
                print('Item:', item, '\n')
            else:
                print('You have collected all of the items in this room.\n')

        # Display user input
        user_input = input('Enter your move:' + '\n' + '> ')  # Movement control
        print('')  # Space for visual formatting
        user_input = user_input.capitalize()  # Capitalize user input to match dictionary
        print('<>' * 50)
        if user_input in move_direction:
            user_input = user_input
            if user_input in rooms[current_room].keys():
                current_room = rooms[current_room][user_input]
                print(current_room)
                print('<>' * 50)
            else:
                # for invalid movement
                print('You can\'t go there!')
                print('<>' * 50)
        # Check for exit command
        elif user_input == 'Exit':
            print('Thank you for playing!')
            print('<>' * 50)
            break

        # invalid command
        elif 'Take' not in user_input:
            print('Invalid input\n')

        if current_room != 'Terrace' and current_room != 'Dragon Pit':
            item = rooms[current_room]['item']

        # Update inventory
        if 'Take' in user_input and current_room != 'Terrace' and item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(item)
            print('You found:', item)
            print('<>' * 50)
        if current_room == 'Terrace' and 'Take' in user_input:
            print('There is no item here!')
            print('<>' * 50)

        # Game over
        if len(inventory) == 6 and current_room == 'Dragon Pit':
            print('\nYou have defeated the Dragons and saved the Seven Kingdoms!')
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            restart_game()
        elif len(inventory) < 6 and current_room == 'Dragon Pit':
            print('\nYou died.')
            print('Collect all six items before facing the Dragons...')
            restart_game()


        def restart_game():
            # Restart or exit game
            restart = input('Play again? (y,n):\n> ')
            if restart == 'y':
                start_menu()
                gameplay_loop()
            if restart == 'n':
                print('Goodbye.')
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print('Invalid input')
            restart_game()

gameplay_loop()
```

`

I tried adding this to my code but it still just accepts 'Take' for user input.

`

```
# invalid command
        elif ('Take'+item) not in user_input:
            print('Invalid input\n')
```

`

Comment: You probably want `continue` after that print so it skips the rest of the loop.  Right now, you just print the message and move on.

Comment: If I add `continue` after the print it returns invalid input for any input. I believe there are conflicts somewhere outside of the `elif` statement, but I'm not sure where they are occuring.

Comment: If understand correctly you want to check Take + Items has to be there else it is invalid

Comment: Well, you aren't validating that the thing they tried to take is actually in the room.  You'll need to split their input into words to do that.

Comment: @twister_void Yes that looks closer to what I am trying to do. I will test and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: You have made this impossible.  "s.capitalize" capitalizes only the first word of the string, so "Take dragon necklace" will never match "Dragon Necklace".  And if you use "s.title()" to capitalize each word, then you can't match "Milk of the Poppy".  It would be better for you to EVERYTHING in lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operates the way you expect.  I've made several changes in the organization here.  I have removed all of your "automatic capitalization", so you must type the command exactly.  I have removed all of your recursive calls and replaced them with loops -- this is not a proper use of recursion.

I also deleted your block title because I didn't want to deal with the character set.  You can add that back in.

```
import sys

def start_menu():
    # Print start menu and commands
    print('<>' * 50)
    print('You are a Spy visiting the Great Pyramid of Meereen. You must make your way from the top of the\n'
          'Pyramid to the Dragon Pit. Collect all of the items along the way to help defeat the two Dragons.\n'
          'If you are successful you will put an end to Queen Daenerys reign and save the Seven Kingdoms.\n'
          '\nHappy Adventuring!')
    print('<>' * 50)
    print('Input move: North, South, East or West')
    print('Input "Take [item name]" to add item to inventory')
    print('Input "Exit" to quit game')
    print('<>' * 50)

# Dictionary of rooms and items
rooms = {
        'Terrace': {'East': 'Daenerys Chambers'},
        'Daenerys Chambers': {'West': 'Terrace', 'East': 'Barristan\'s Chambers', 'South': 'Royal Chambers',
                              'item': 'Dragon Necklace'},
        'Barristan\'s Chambers': {'West': 'Daenerys Chambers', 'item': 'Barristan\'s Sword'},
        'Royal Chambers': {'North': 'Daenerys Chambers', 'South': 'Torture Cells',
                           'West': 'Audience Chamber', 'East': 'Stables', 'item': 'Milk of the Poppy'},
        'Audience Chamber': {'East': 'Royal Chambers', 'item': 'Torch'},
        'Stables': {'West': 'Royal Chambers', 'item': 'Health Potion'},
        'Torture Cells': {'North': 'Royal Chambers', 'East': 'Dragon Pit', 'item': 'Magic Potion'},
        'Dragon Pit': {'West': 'Torture Cells', 'Item': 'Dragons'}
    }

def gameplay_loop():
    move_direction = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
    inventory = []
    current_room = 'Terrace'

    # Gameplay loop
    while True:
        # Display Inventory
        print('Inventory', inventory, '\n')

        if current_room == 'Terrace':
            print('You are on the {}.\n'.format(current_room))
        else:
            print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))
            if current_room == 'Torture Cells':
                print('A sign reads: "Beware of Dragon Pit: East"')

        item = None
        if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
            item = rooms[current_room]['item']
            if item in inventory:
                print('You have collected all of the items in this room.\n')
                item = None
            else:
                print('Item:', item, '\n')

        # Display user input
        user_input = input('Enter your move:' + '\n' + '> ')  # Movement control
        print('')  # Space for visual formatting
#        user_input = user_input.title()  # Capitalize each word
        print('<>' * 50)
        if user_input in move_direction:
            user_input = user_input
            if user_input in rooms[current_room].keys():
                current_room = rooms[current_room][user_input]
                print(current_room)
                print('<>' * 50)
            else:
                # for invalid movement
                print('You can\'t go there!')
                print('<>' * 50)
            continue
        # Check for exit command
        elif user_input == 'Exit':
            print('Thank you for playing!')
            print('<>' * 50)
            break

        # invalid command
        elif 'Take' not in user_input:
            print('Invalid input\n')
            continue

        # What item did they want?
        want = user_input[5:]

        if want != item:
            print("That item is not available.")
            continue

        # Update inventory
        if current_room != 'Terrace' and item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(item)
            print('You found:', item)
            print('<>' * 50)

        # Check for game over
        if len(inventory) == 6 and current_room == 'Dragon Pit':
            print('\nYou have defeated the Dragons and saved the Seven Kingdoms!')
            print('Thanks for playing!')
        elif len(inventory) < 6 and current_room == 'Dragon Pit':
            print('\nYou died.')
            print('Collect all six items before facing the Dragons...')

    while True:
        # Restart or exit game
        restart = input('Play again? (y,n):\n> ')
        if restart == 'y':
            start_menu()
            return True
        if restart == 'n':
            print('Goodbye.')
            return False
        print('Invalid input')

start_menu()
while gameplay_loop():
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot! I am not too familiar with recursion so thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

To validate Take + Items, you need to read input and store them somthing like below if i understand correctly .

````py
        # Check for Take in input and Item name
        elif 'Take' in user_input:
            item = user_input[5:]
            if item in rooms[current_room].values():
                inventory.append(item)
                print('You have added {} to your inventory.'.format(item))
                print('<>' * 50)
            else:
                print('You can\'t take that!')
                print('<>' * 50)```
````